# Closed form of f(x) for $x f(x)^2 - f(x) + 1 = 0$

Tags: closed-form

In a [slide](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/algo08-tutorials/tutorial-catalan.pdf) it says that the closed form of $f(x)$ is $f(x)=(1-\sqrt{1-4x})/(2x)$, given that
$$x f(x)^2 - f(x) + 1 = 0.$$

However, I don't see how to derive it.
I tried to take derivative wrt $x$ for both sides, but failed to proceed further.
$$f(x)^2 + 2xf(x)f^\prime - f^\prime = 0.$$

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Solve the quadratic equation with $x$ constant for the variable $f(x)$. i.e. find $y$ where $xy^2-y+1=0$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks! You are right.